# Terrafrom | variable | input to bash script

Tags: terraform, terraform-template-file

I have veraibles in varibles.tf files in terraf from

```
locals {
deployment-type  = lower(var.env)
```

I am making an instance that will join ecs cluster. I need to inject cluster name in the Template file from TF vars

```
 resource "aws_instance" "ec2-instance" {......
 user_data = "${data.template_file.user_data.rendered}"
  data "template_file" "user_data" {
 template = "${file("${path.module}/user_data.tpl")}"
}
```

Here is tpl file. I need to inject cluster name in this file from TF vars

````
# Update all packages

sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install -y ecs-init
sudo service docker start
sudo start ecs
echo "${var.env}"
#Adding cluster name in ecs config
#echo "${var.source_dest_check}"= >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
cat /etc/ecs/ecs.config | grep "ECS_CLUSTER"```
````

Comment: What's wrong with what you're doing? It looks like you understand that you need to append a line to your ECS config file but you aren't showing an error in your question or explaining what isn't working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top, I think you are not supposed to use `${var.env}` in the template, but rather `${env}`.

There are multiple parts to how this works. I'll have to assume you are missing one of these parts. I can provide a simple example.

From my own userdata definitions, some greatly-simplified samples:

```
variable "product" {
  default = ""
}

data "template_file" "userdata" {
  template = file("${path.module}/userdata.sh")
  vars = {
    product             = var.product
  }
}
```

From my `terraform.tfvars` file:

```
product = "radar"
```

Somewhere in the file `userdata.sh`, which is the template:

```
    "product": "${product}",
```

The template is of course more complex than this. I'd suggest starting with a simple file and checking that it came out looking like you want, then build on that. Once you see the vars flowing through the chain as you want, it should be simple to build out a more complex bootstrap.